# ratio of "diameter" of a n-gon to perimeter

Tags: pi, polygons

So say I have a regular polygon with n sides, and I bisect the an angle E such and the line (EF). Assume line segment EF has length b, while the polygons side length is s. What is $b/(n*s)$, and as n approaches $\infty$ does $b/(n*s)$ approach $\pi$?

Comment: http://ggbtu.be/mqdqawziZ for an example

Answer (score 0):

So what we need to do here, is to define our angles: $\theta$ and $ \phi $, where: 

$ \theta   = \frac{\pi \cdot (n-2)}{n} $ and $\phi =\pi-2\theta$.
Now, applying the law of sines: 
$ \frac{\sin \theta}{\frac{1}{2}b} = \frac{\sin \phi}{s} $ 
Then, you're all set up to continue on for your calculations!

Comment: what does phi in this case represent?

Comment: $\phi$ is the interior angle between two sides, i.e. the equivalent to an arc angle for a circle (trends to $0$ as $n$ $\rightarrow \infty$)